# Why xlC compiler on aix always generates different object files for the same c++ source code?

Tags: c++, aix, xlc

When I compile a simple test.cpp file twice using xlC compiler on AIX:

```
xlC_r test.cpp -o test1
xlC_r test.cpp -o test2
```

Then test1 and test2 are diffrent! They have diffrent md5sum.

But when I do the same on linux (with g++ of course instead of xlc) then test1 and test2 are the same...

Anybody please could tell me why this strange behavior happens in AIX??

Thanks

Comment: Datestamps in the executable? Randomized names of some kind? You really need to compare the actual files more closely (all sections, disassembly, etc.)

Comment: Maybe you can try to do a binary diff on them? They could contain some kind of unique id, for example, or the order of the contained functions could be different

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the compiler stores a timestamp in each object file that it creates. As of Version 12.1 of the compiler, one can specify the option -qnotimestamps when compiling to suppress the storing of timestamps.

Comment: The user is looking at final executables.  Aren't there timestamps also in the executable format itself?  i.e. I thought doing two links would also produce two slightly different files.

Comment: I tried to use -qnotimestamps but still the binaries are diffrent

Comment: Try using the dump command to dump a text version of the XCOFF executables and compare those--should help narrow down the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it includes a timestamp in the compiled program. You could try and find where they differ by saving an octal or headecimal dump of each program and comparing the results. Many UNIX variants provide the `od` and `diff` programs which you could use, but I don't know if they are available under AIX.

Comment: `od` and `diff` are both Posix, so should be available on any Unix platform (or with CygWin under Windows).

Comment: Certainly. I just wasn't sure whether they are always present or only when some optional package is installed.